# Unable to connect to SharePoint list using Microsoft365R

Tags: r, sharepoint

I get the following error after authenticating in RStudio.

```
Loading Microsoft Graph login for default tenant
Error: Site 'site name' not found
```

I am using the Microsoft365R package for R. We have multifactor authentication enabled.

```
site <- Microsoft365R::get_sharepoint_site("sitename")
```

The above is the code that is run. It asks me to authenticate in browser, which I do, before it tells me no such site exists (it does).

Do I need to change some permissions somewhere?

Comment: how exactly are you identifying the site?

Comment: Exactly as above, but with the site url instead of a "sitename".

So instead of "sitename" it would be https://www.somesite.com/sites/sitename

Comment: I would like to establish if there are any typos or missing "http" or other things that can go wrong. If that's too hard, then let's leave it.

Comment: No typos, that I can assure you of.

Comment: Another piece of context that will help rule out the above. After running the package command that lists all sites, the site I am attempting to reference does not appear. In fact, a lot of sites do not. The sites that do appear (there are 5 total) do not appear to have any clear distinguishing differences. I am also full admin on sharepoint and there are no differences in any of the settings. The sites are identical and I am an owner of all of them.